# Visual Studio Code code completion for Java not working

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code is not giving me any code completion for Java (just the word completion):

[image]

I have the JDKs configured:

```json
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
    {
        "name": "JavaSE-11",
        "path": "/usr/lib/jvm/jre-11-openjdk",
        "default": true
    },
    {
        "name": "JavaSE-17",
        "path": "/usr/lib/jvm/jre-17-openjdk",
    }   
]
```

I have the *Extension Pack* for Java installed and I don't get any error or something.

Any other suggestions what might be the problem?

`Help: About`

```
Version: 1.83.1
Commit: f1b07bd25dfad64b0167beb15359ae573aecd2cc
Date: 2023-10-10T23:45:31.402Z
Electron: 25.8.4
ElectronBuildId: 24154031
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.5.8-200.fc38.x86_64
```

Red Hat Java Extension is v1.24.0 (I also tried rolling back to v1.23.0)

**EDIT**

Now I do get some errors:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceManager.getPreferences()" because the return value of "org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.JavaLanguageServerPlugin.getPreferencesManager()" is null
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.preferences.Preferences.setJavaCompletionFavoriteMembers(Preferences.java:1378)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.preferences.Preferences.createFrom(Preferences.java:1126)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.BaseInitHandler.handleInitializationOptions(BaseInitHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.InitHandler.handleInitializationOptions(InitHandler.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.BaseInitHandler.initialize(BaseInitHandler.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.JDTLanguageServer.initialize(JDTLanguageServer.java:284)
    ... 16 more
```

This error keeps coming and coming. The anlysis of the Java project never ends. Strangely while the analysis runs, the code completion now works.

**EDIT**

I did update to Java 17 on my machine, now at least the error messages are gone, but I still get no code completion for Java.

```
Fedora 38
OpenJDK 17.0.8
```

Comment: Is this set? `"java.jdt.ls.java.home": "E:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17.0.5"` (jdk17 or above)

Comment: It was not. But setting it did not solve the problem. I also was using Java 11 and switched to 17 but that did also not help.

Comment: Can you provide a specific example showing how code completion isn't working?

Comment: I added a picture. I only get some word completion but nothing Java specific.

Comment: [the maintainers are asking for more info](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/3349#issuecomment-1790841036): "are there any other errors in your logs before the NullPointerException regarding JavaLanguageServerPlugin.getPreferencesManager() ? Would you be able to attach the client/server logs of this occuring ?" If you could reply to that comment there, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, this is so stupid. I forgot to set some properties in my maven configuration.

I set the Java version in the compiler plugin using two properties:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
        <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But I forgot to set both of these properties. Strange this is, I did not get any error message, that they are not set.
But I did also not build the project on the console.

After defining the properties, everything worked as it should.

So, thanks for all your help! And sorry for wasting your time!

Answer (score 0):

From the description of the symptoms in the question post- namely that a stacktrace containing `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceManager.getPreferences()" because the return value of "org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.JavaLanguageServerPlugin.getPreferencesManager()" is null` is getting spammed in the logs, I think this is a case of this issue: [is it is expected to have 19 GB of 1.1 mb log files in worksapceStorage
#3349](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/3349#issue-1955416683). see the info request [here](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/3349#issuecomment-1786194295). The issue is purportedly fixed by pull request [Avoid refreshing bundles whose dependency closure includes JDT-LS. #2951](https://github.com/eclipse-jdtls/eclipse.jdt.ls/pull/2951), which is in the End November 2023 release milestone.

#### Extra info

[Provided logs show that](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/3349#issuecomment-1792627772) the failure happens when the extension tries to get a reference to the bundle context for `jdt.ls.core`- after which it seems to get stuck in an initialize loop due to the startup error. The changes made in v1.25.2023110903 of the extension seem to improve but not completely fix the bug.

The timing of this question lines up nicely with the release of [version 1.24.0 of the extension](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/releases/tag/v1.24.0), so I suspect it being a bug introduced in 1.24.0.

Comment: After updatiing to Java 17 at least the errors are gone, but I still get no code completion. Rolling back to v1.23 of the extension did also not help.